# Confusion in "mask bits"

Tags: exponentiation

This is the question:

> By definition of the IEEE754 standard, 32-bit floating point numbers
>   are represented as  follows:
>
> S (1 bit)  E (8 bits)  M (23 bits)  S: Sign bit  E: Exponent  M:
>   Mantissa
>
> Which of the following is the correct “mask bits” in hexadecimal to be
>   used for  extracting only the exponent part of the above format?
>   Here, “mask bits” means a bit  pattern which is logically ANDed
>   withthe 32-bit floating point value.
>
> a) 107FFFFF  b)  7F800000  c)  FF100000  d) FF800000

The given answer is b : 7F800000, but i have no idea why, can anyone give me an explanation, i'm greatly appreciated!

Is that because :

7F800000 = 0**111 1111 1**000 (8)

While other answers contain more `"1"` in binary format?

Answer (score 0):

a 32-bit floating point numbers is a sequence of 32 bits. According to the definitions, the bits are arranged as follows

[S][EEEEEEEE][MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM]

Thus, the mask we want is:
[0][11111111][00000000000000000000000]

Now, we remove the grouping and turn it to hexadecimal...

0111 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

which translates to (b).